# Save a collection of dicts to output file in Python

Tags: python, io

I'm streaming data via API that's returned in the form of nested dictionaries in Python.

Sample dict below:

```
msg = {'command': 'SUBS',
 'content': [{'ASK_ID': '?',
              'ASK_PRICE': 4176.75,
              'ASK_SIZE': 28,
              'BID_ID': '?',
              'BID_PRICE': 4176.5,
              'BID_SIZE': 16,
              'CLOSE_PRICE': 4180,
              'DESCRIPTION': 'E-mini S&P 500 Index Futures,Jun-2023,ETH',
              'EXCHANGE_ID': 'E',
              'EXCHANGE_NAME': 'XCME',
              'FUTURE_ACTIVE_SYMBOL': '/ESM23',
              'FUTURE_EXPIRATION_DATE': 1686888000000,
              'FUTURE_IS_ACTIVE': True,
              'FUTURE_IS_TRADEABLE': True,
              'FUTURE_MULTIPLIER': 50,
              'FUTURE_PERCENT_CHANGE': -0.00083732,
              'FUTURE_PRICE_FORMAT': 'D,D',
              'FUTURE_SETTLEMENT_PRICE': 4180,
              'FUTURE_TRADING_HOURS': 'GLBX(de=1640;0=-17001600;1=r-17001600d-15551640;7=d-16401555)',
              'HIGH_PRICE': 4178.5,
              'LAST_ID': '?',
              'LAST_PRICE': 4176.5,
              'LAST_SIZE': 1,
              'LOW_PRICE': 4175,
              'MARK': 4176.5,
              'NET_CHANGE': -3.5,
              'OPEN_INTEREST': 2253394,
              'OPEN_PRICE': 4176,
              'PRODUCT': '/ES',
              'QUOTE_TIME': 1681865406987,
              'SECURITY_STATUS': 'Unknown',
              'TICK': 0.25,
              'TICK_AMOUNT': 12.5,
              'TOTAL_VOLUME': 10520,
              'TRADE_TIME': 1681865403677,
              'delayed': False,
              'key': '/ES'},
             {'ASK_ID': '?',
              'ASK_PRICE': 80.97,
              'ASK_SIZE': 3,
              'BID_ID': '?',
              'BID_PRICE': 80.96,
              'BID_SIZE': 4,
              'CLOSE_PRICE': 80.9,
              'DESCRIPTION': 'Light Sweet Crude Oil Futures,Jun-2023,ETH',
              'EXCHANGE_ID': 'E',
              'EXCHANGE_NAME': 'XNYM',
              'FUTURE_ACTIVE_SYMBOL': '/CLM23',
              'FUTURE_EXPIRATION_DATE': 1684728000000,
              'FUTURE_IS_ACTIVE': True,
              'FUTURE_IS_TRADEABLE': True,
              'FUTURE_MULTIPLIER': 1000,
              'FUTURE_PERCENT_CHANGE': 0.00086527,
              'FUTURE_PRICE_FORMAT': 'D,D',
              'FUTURE_SETTLEMENT_PRICE': 80.9,
              'FUTURE_TRADING_HOURS': 'GLBX(de=1640;0=-17001600;1=-17001600d-15551640;7=d-16401555)',
              'HIGH_PRICE': 81.05,
              'LAST_ID': '?',
              'LAST_PRICE': 80.97,
              'LAST_SIZE': 1,
              'LOW_PRICE': 80.9,
              'MARK': 80.97,
              'NET_CHANGE': 0.07,
              'OPEN_INTEREST': 379191,
              'OPEN_PRICE': 80.96,
              'PRODUCT': '/CL',
              'QUOTE_TIME': 1681865406214,
              'SECURITY_STATUS': 'Unknown',
              'TICK': 0.01,
              'TICK_AMOUNT': 10,
              'TOTAL_VOLUME': 2847,
              'TRADE_TIME': 1681865405297,
              'delayed': False,
              'key': '/CL'}],
 'service': 'LEVELONE_FUTURES',
 'timestamp': 1681865409894}
```

I ultimately need to keep the 'service', 'timestamp' and 'content' keys/values, with 'content' constituting most of the actual data.  What's the best way to save this to a flat file (either txt or csv) for saving and later use?

I'm currently working with the below, which seems to work fine, but wonder if there's a better approach (in terms of space savings and ease of consumption later--I'll be reading back into Python) or if I'm just overthinking this.  Sample CSV output included below as well.

```
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
        while True:
            msg = await self.queue.get()
            b = pd.json_normalize(msg, record_path=['content'])
            b['timestamp'] = msg['timestamp']
            b['service'] = msg['service']
            b.to_csv(f, index=False)
         
            pprint.pprint(msg)
```

[image]

Comment: If you're concerned about space occupied on disk, you could compress the file you save (`gzip` module in the standard library). Looks like it will be quite compressible with the amount of repetition.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, completely fair, just what I've used before and no good reason, just took up less space on disk than a text file.  is there a preferable io-module/method to do this?

Comment: @slothrop, thanks.  had considered that, but this will be running until stopped, how to apply compression as part of that process (ie, can only compress the file 'at the end', but there's not really an end)?

Comment: I'd probably use a database for this—maybe SQLite. If you don't want to use a database, you could use [zstandard](https://python-zstandard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which has a streaming compression API. I can't give much help on that, though, because I haven't used it.

Comment: `gzip` can abstract the "compressing at the end" side of it from you - you can open a `GzipFileObject`, write to it as if it were a normal file, and the data is buffered and compressed on close. See for example the "Lots of content here" example in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage